# How to get count of values based on datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have written the following code which creates two dataframes `nq` and `cmnt`.
`nq` contains the `UserId` and corresponding time of Badge Attainment `date`.
`cmnt` contains `OwnerUserId` and the time when the User made a comment `CreationDate`.
I want to get a count of the comments made for all days before and after 1 week of badge attainment so that I can create a time series line plot out of it.

The following code perform the same but produces a KeyError. Please provide a code that performs this operations for all users.

**nq**

```
 UserId |   date 
     1      2009-10-17 17:38:32.590
     2      2009-10-19 00:37:23.067
     3      2009-10-20 08:37:14.143
     4      2009-10-21 18:07:51.247
     5      2009-10-22 21:25:24.483
```

**cmnt**

```
OwnerUserId | CreationDate
1             2009-10-16 17:38:32.590
1             2009-10-18 17:38:32.590
2             2009-10-18 00:37:23.067
2             2009-10-17 00:37:23.067
2             2009-10-20 00:37:23.067
3             2009-10-19 08:37:14.143
4             2009-10-20 18:07:51.247
5             2009-10-21 21:25:24.483
```

**code**

```
 nq.date = pd.to_datetime(nq.date)
 cmnt.CreationDate = pd.to_datetime(cmnt.CreationDate)

 count= []
   
 for j in range(len(nq)): 
      for i in range(-7,8):
        
          check_date = nq.date.iloc[j] + timedelta(days=i)
          
          count = cmnt.loc[(cmnt.OwnerUserId == nq.UserId.iloc[j]) & (cmnt.CreationDate == check_date)].shape[0]
          nq.iloc[j].append({nq[i]:count})
```

**expected output**

```
UserId     |   date                 |-7|-6|-5|-4|-3|-2|-1|0 |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7
     1      2009-10-17 17:38:32.590 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0  
     2      2009-10-19 00:37:23.067 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |1 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0    
     3      2009-10-20 08:37:14.143 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     4      2009-10-21 18:07:51.247 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     5      2009-10-22 21:25:24.483 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0
```

Here column `-1` means comment made 1 day before badge attainment and `1` means comment made one day after badge attainment and so on.

**Note**
There can be a completely alternately way to do this. My main objective is to draw a time series line plot which shows the number of comments made by the users before and after attainment of the badge.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @Roy2012 I have added the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that:

```
t = pd.merge(nq, cmnt, left_on="UserId", right_on = "OwnerUserId")
t["days_diff"] = (t["CreationDate"] - t["date"]).dt.days
t["count"] = t.groupby(["UserId", "days_diff"]).OwnerUserId.transform("count")

all_days = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(t.UserId.unique(), range(-7, 8)), )
all_days.columns = ["UserId", "day"]

t = pd.merge(t, all_days, left_on=["UserId", "days_diff"], right_on=["UserId", "day"], how = "right")
t = pd.pivot_table(t, index="UserId", columns="day", values="count", dropna=False)

res = pd.merge(nq, t, left_on="UserId", right_index=True)

print(res)
```

The output is:

```
   UserId                    date  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3   -2   -1   0    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0       1 2009-10-17 17:38:32.590 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1       2 2009-10-19 00:37:23.067 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2       3 2009-10-20 08:37:14.143 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3       4 2009-10-21 18:07:51.247 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4       5 2009-10-22 21:25:24.483 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Is there a way to plot this graph without having to create this DataFrame?

Comment: This data frame seems like a reasonable way to plot this chart. In any case, if the above answer answers your question it would be great if you could accept it for future generations.

Comment: What keeps loading?

Comment: Okay. Got it. I’ll try to see if I can optimize it.

Comment: By tweaking large dataframe a bit this code works perfectly fine, it does not need any changes.

Comment: How can we get the same output if the data is present in two xml files instead of two dataframes? Additionally, the output cannot be stored in a dataframe as the files are more than 50 gb each, so the RAM would crash if I try to work on such a big dataframe.

Comment: can you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63763935/merging-2-dataframes-based-on-datetime-feature for help?

Comment: Sure. Will have a look.

Comment: This code causes an error for some part of the data for this code line `all_days.columns = ["UserId", "day"]`. Error is `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 2 elements`. This is absurd because the code works fine for some part but throws an error for another part of data. Is there a way to fix this?