# How to add new column data by individual rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe `df`. I want to add 2 new columns `0` and `1` and add data to these columns by one row at a time, and not the complete column at once. By using `pd.Series` for all the rows in `df` I am getting `NaN` value in the new column data other than the last row. Provide me a way to fix this.

I need to add data by one row at a time. Please provide solution accordingly.

**df**

```
val
1
2
3
```

**code**

```
for j in range(len(df)):
  for i in range(2):
    cal = df.val.iloc[j] + 10
    df[i] = pd.Series(cal, index=df.index[[j]])
```

**output**

```
val |   0   | 1
1   | NaN   | NaN
2   | NaN   | NaN
3   | 13.0  | 13.0
```

**expected output**

```
    val |   0   | 1
    1   | 11.0  | 11.0
    2   | 12.0  | 12.0
    3   | 13.0  | 13.0
```

**EDIT**
I had actually asked a question on stackoverflow whose answer I could not get. That is why I had tried to condense the question and present it this way. If possible you all can check the original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958702/how-to-get-count-of-values-based-on-datetime-in-python)

Comment: Why are you trying to add data on row at a time? That goes against what pandas is meant for.

Comment: Actually this is a condensed form of my problem which I had actually asked on stackoverflow but did not get an answer. So I thought of presenting the same in an easier way. You can check my original question and answer there @user3483203 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958702/how-to-get-count-of-values-based-on-datetime-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you are trying to add rows one at a time with inefficient methods, hence I suggest not to use this code but to rely on vectorized solutions.

However, if you really want to do it for some reason, you should modify your cycle like this

```
for j in range(len(df)):
    for i in range(2):
        cal = df.val.iloc[j] + 10
        df.loc[j, i] = cal

#    val     0     1
# 0    1  11.0  11.0
# 1    2  12.0  12.0
# 2    3  13.0  13.0
```

Comment: Please check my Question Edit. It explains why I wrote this code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` function

```
In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   val
0    1
1    2
2    3
In [13]: df[0] = df["val"].apply(lambda x: x + 10)

In [14]: df[1] = df["val"].apply(lambda x: x + 10)

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   val   0   1
0    1  11  11
1    2  12  12
2    3  13  13
```

Or use `iterrows`

```
In [21]: temp = []

In [22]: for inex,row in df.iterrows():
    ...:     temp.append(row["val"] + 10)
    ...:

In [23]: temp
Out[23]: [11, 12, 13]

In [24]: df[0] = temp

In [25]: df[1] = temp

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
   val   0   1
0    1  11  11
1    2  12  12
2    3  13  13
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - you should **NOT** use this code. It's the wrong way. But - given that you want to do it row by row, here's a solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"val": [1,2, 3]})

for i in df.index:
    val = df.loc[i, "val"]
    for j in [0,1]:
        df.loc[i, j] = val + 10
print(df)

==>
   val     0     1
0    1  11.0  11.0
1    2  12.0  12.0
2    3  13.0  13.0
```

The proper way would be to do something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"val": [1,2, 3]})
df[0] = df.val + 10
df[1] = df.val + 10
```

Same results basically, much better when it comes to pandas.

Comment: Do it in a vectorized manner, and not row by row. I'll add the proper way to my answer.

Comment: @baxx - it does. And AFAIK, the plus operator calls the add method of the series.

Comment: Please check the Question Edit.

Answer (score -1):

maybe:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df["val"].iloc[i] = df.val.iloc[i] + 10
```