# Merging 2 DataFrames based on DateTime feature

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

I have the following 2 DataFrames `question_posts` and `nice_question`. `question_posts` has multiple entries for every user whereas `nice_question` has unique `UserId` values.

**Part of question_posts**

```
OwnerUserId | CreationDate             | Score
981         |2009-09-28 16:11:38.533   |  50
483         | 2009-10-18 15:11:20.533  | 700
698         | 2010-09-28 16:11:35.533  |   0
10          | 2009-01-28 10:12:38.7    | 200
```

**Part of nice_question**

```
UserId | Date
981    | 2009-10-17 17:38:32.59
10     | 2009-10-20 08:37:14.143
290    | 2009-10-20 18:07:51.247
699    | 2009-10-20 21:25:24.483
```

I want to create a new feature in the `nice_question` dataframe called `Quality Factor` which should be based on the `average score = total score/total posts` obtained from the `question_posts` dataframe. The `average score` should  be computed for posts made by user before the `date` provided in `nice_question`.

I have tried the following code but I get an error.

**Code**

```
nice_question['Quality Factor'] = (question_posts.loc[question_posts['CreationDate']<nice_question['date']]).sum()
```

**Error**

```
Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

**Expected Output**

```
>>nice_question.head(4)

>> UserId | Date                     | Quality Factor
    981    | 2009-10-17 17:38:32.59  | 5
    10     | 2009-10-20 08:37:14.143 | 16
    290    | 2009-10-20 18:07:51.247 | 66
    699    | 2009-10-20 21:25:24.483 | 9
```

Comment: I don't understand the expected results. user 981 has only one question, with score 50. How come the quality factor / average score is 5? (the same question applies to the other users).

Comment: @Roy2012 this is just a part of data, the dataframe `question_posts` has multiple entries for the same user(all of which have not been mentioned in the above question that is why the `Quality Factor` does not match). The second dataframe `nice_question` has only unique `UserId` value and in that we do the required aggregation to find the value of `Quality Factor`.

Comment: See my answer below. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution (in a few steps, for clarity):

```
t = pd.merge(nice_question, question_post, left_on = "UserId", right_on= "OwnerUserId", how = "left")
t = t[t.CreationDate < t.Date]
avg_scores = t.groupby("UserId")[["Score"]].mean()
avg_scores = avg_scores.rename(columns = {"Score": "avg_score"})
res = pd.merge(nice_question, avg_scores, left_on="UserId", right_index=True)
```

For the sample data, the result is:

```
   UserId                     Date  avg_score
0     981   2009-10-17 17:38:32.59       50.0
1      10  2009-10-20 08:37:14.143      200.0
```

Comment: This works perfectly for this problem. But if I want to remove rows from `nice_question` based on the same logic without merging the dataframes then this code line `nice_question =nice_question[nice_question.CreationDate < question_post.Date]` produces error `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This code line doesn't work because as it is written it's a pairwise comparison between every row of the first dataframe and the second one.

```
nice_question['Quality Factor'] = (question_posts.loc[question_posts['CreationDate']<nice_question['date']]).sum()
```

If the two dataframe have the same size (num of rows) this will work. But it is not what you want

To obtain what you want you should work with [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) pandas methods

For example in this way I obtain a new df in which I can do your comparison per row

```
new_df = pd.merge(question_posts,
                  nice_question,
                  left_on='OwnerUserId',
                  right_on='UserId', how='outer')
```

Comment: But how to put the datetime condition to get the required output?

Comment: @IshanDutta `new_df = new_df[(new_df['CreationDate']<new_df['date'])]` then you can work with aggregation